# C structure with nested same structure (linked) hiding a private member, shall work?

Tags: c

I want to hide my real struct from my library.

in private.h I have defined like this

```
    typedef void (*LoadValidateFunc_t)(void);
    typedef struct Car_t
    {
        struct Car_t *Next;
        LoadValidateFunc_t LoadValidate; // member to hide
        struct MyPrivateStruct_t Test; // also to hide
    } Car_t;
Car_t* MyCar = ((Car_t*)&((Car_t) { NULL, &cbProcess }));
```

in some public.h I have defined like this

```
    typedef struct Car_t
    {
        struct Car_t *Next;
        // void *LoadValidate;  // <-- should I keep this ? I want to hide all not necesairly
    
    } Car_t;
extern Car_t* MyCar;
```

Now this compiles just fine.

If I don't create any new, public cars, should be fine to omit (hide) *LoadValidate ?
Meaning that calling (public domain) my func from library will receive the same object and perfectly safe, right?

```
MyFuncFromLib(MyCar)
```

But what if I create new cars in public domain?
According to my understanding, will be a completely different object type (from public);

So in this case I should populate public struct with void* just in order to keep the same size?
How to reserve space for MyPrivateStruct_t ?

Thanks for clarifications!

Comment: Like this, [private: [car: next] LoadValidate, Test]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to hide my real struct from my library.

If you insist on doing this, then make the struct type opaque in the public headers.

> in private.h I have [one definition of `struct Car_t` ... and]

> in some public.h I have [a definition of `struct Car_t` omitting some trailing members]

> Now this compiles just fine.

It's hard to tell what you mean by "this".  One does not usually compile headers alone. If you did, though, then I presume that neither of those headers `#include`s the other, so there is no exposure of one to the other.

If you also compiled code that used those headers, then I have to assume that no translation unit `#include`s both, because if one did, then a conforming compiler would be obliged to emit a diagnostic about the mismatch.  Supposing that no code sees both headers, the discrepancy does not itself provide any reason for compilation failure.

> If I don't create any new, public cars, should be fine to omit (hide) *LoadValidate ?

Probably not.  There are conditions under which it would be ok for both of those incompatible type definitions to be used in the same program, but they are considerably more stringent than you describe.

> Meaning that calling (public domain) my func from library will receive the same object and perfectly safe, right?

**Absolutely not.**  Not the same object no matter what (C has only pass-by-value semantics).  Not at all safe.  How likely it is that the program will seem to work as expected depends on details of what it tries to do, but even if it seems to work as you expect, there might be hidden misbehavior or misbehavior under uncommon circumstances, or it might break if you change compilation options or use a different compiler, or when you modify the code in seemingly unrelated ways.

Details:

C does not have any sense of *the same* structure type declared in different translation units.  Each translation unit's type declarations are its own.  Instead, C relies on the concept of *compatible* types.  Two structure types  declared in different translation units, both with tags and members, are compatible only if the tags are the same, the number of members is the same, and corresponding members have compatible types (these are not all the requirements).

Thus, a structure type declared in one translation unit according to one of those definitions is not compatible with a structure type declared in a different translation unit according to the other.  Neither are types derived from those compatible with each other, such as pointers to those types or qualified versions of those types, or unions or aggregates containing members with those types or derived from those types, recursively.

Nor are declarations of the same external function identifier compatible if they declare return or parameter types from among those derived in any way from the incompatible structure types.

If a program accesses an object via an lvalue whose type is not compatible with the object's own effective type (and which also does not satisify any of a handful of other conditions that do not apply here), then the behavior is undefined.  If a program calls a function from within the scope of a declaration of that function that is incompatible with its definition, then the behavior is undefined.

If you are passing or returning instances of the structure types in question then the resulting UB is very likely to manifest as serious misbehavior, such as program crashes and other incorrect operation.  If you are working only in terms of pointers to these structures then the behavior is still undefined, but depending on a wide variety of variables, you might luck into program behavior that seems to be consistent with your expectations.  That's worse than obvious misbehavior, because it may hide non-obvious misbehavior, or there may still be problems under uncommon circumstances.

> But what if I create new cars in public domain? According to my
> understanding, will be a completely different object type (from
> public);

Exactly.  You can create them, but you cannot *exchange* them with your private library code.

> So in this case I should populate public struct with void* just in
> order to keep the same size?

No.  That does not rescue the situation.

> How to reserve space for
> MyPrivateStruct_t ?

It's not about the space.  Structure types having the same tag and size is not sufficient for them to be compatible, nor even for them to *seem* compatible.

You have two main choices:

1. Don't bother trying to hide members, at least not in the library headers.  If you wish, omit the private members from your *documentation*, and perhaps warn explicitly that only the public members should be accessed.  But even this can be problemmatic, as how are the private members supposed to acquire valid values if an instance of the structure is created on the public side?
2. Make the structure opaque.  That is, on the public side provide only a forward declaration, without any members:

   ```
   struct Car_t;
   typedef struct Car_t Car_t;  // optional
   ```

   The public side will then not be able to create instances itself, but it will be able to handle *pointers to* instances.  It will need to rely on library functions to allocate instances and to access their members.